# error trying to access IBM DB2 using python

Tags: python, flask, db2

I tried connecting my python server with IBM DB2 and got this error. I searched online, tried many things and nothing could fix it. I couldn't find the db2dsdriver.config anywhere in the IBM folder. For context, I'm trying to access an online IBM db using a python flask server that I'm running locally

```
    File "server.py", line 8, in <module>
    conn = ibm_db.connect("BLUDB","MyDB2loginhere","psswd")
Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1531N  The connection failed because the name specified with the DSN connection string keyword could not be found in either the db2dsdriver.cfg configuration file or the db2cli.ini configuration file.  Data s SQLCODE=-1531cified in the connection string: "BLUDB"
```

Comment: To connect , you __either__ need a valid DSN (data source name) configured in your operating-system (or db2dsriver.cfg which you can edit, it is an XML file), or you specify the full connection-string as first argument to `ibm_db.connect` in the correct format for Db2 (many examples online).  You cannot mix these methods.

Comment: I think it would be better for me to specify the full connection string. Where can I get it? Can I also use this string to run this server on an IBM cloud?

Comment: You __write__ the connection string (just a piece of text with a specific format), by using the information you have (the hostname that contains the database-server and database, the port-number, the userid, the password, any many other things are possible). this is a FAQ. See https://www.connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2-odbc/

Comment: corrected the link

Comment: I'm lost. What do I put as first argument?

Comment: @Ohhh, try the following: connection string replacing values in equality assignments including numbers, asterisks, and names: `ibm_db.connect("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=48000;Hostname=*****; Database=myDatabase;UID=***;PWD=***;", "", "")`

Comment: You already have an ODBC driver , it comes with ibm_db module, by default. Plenty of examples of Db2 connection strings on google.

Comment: sorry for the dumb question, but what should I replace hostname with?

Comment: Usually that is interchangeable with server. Try omitting it. If DB2 database is on same network with your client machine, you may be able to use `localhost` or the network port database runs on.

Comment: The hostname is the name of the machine (or its IP-address) that has the Db2-database  (for example, the fully qualified name of the cloud service that you might be using).  If the Db2 database is in the cloud you cannot omit this. If the Db2 database is __not__ on your local machine you cannot omit this.

Comment: It worked, thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Answered by comments.

By default when you install python module `ibm_db` it delivers a small ODBC driver from IBM called `clidriver` for connecting to local or remote Db2 databases. Other ODBC drivers are available, including from other suppliers different from IBM. With an IBM supplied driver (including clidriver), an additional license may be required only for accessing Db2-for-Z/OS, or Db2 for i series.  Specifically for i-series, it is cheaper to use the ODBC driver option that is available via IBM product called `IBM i access` (cheaper than buying a license for Db2-connect to use with clidriver).

To connect to a database, you either use an externally configured DSN (data source name), or use a `connection string` in your code.

Externally configured DSNs mean that your code does not hard-code any connectivity details, so it is easier to move between different environments without changing code, because the configuration is all external data. You can also arrange the connection-strings to be external.

To configure an external DSN, either use local tools or edit the `db2dsdriver.cfg` file, which is a small XML file you can create and edit manually or via `db2cli` command lines. Local tools can be `odbcad32` on MS-Windows or `unixODBC` on Linux/Unix/MacOS.  The IBM published documentation in the Db2 Knowledge Center gives all the details of `db2dsdriver.cfg`.

To use a connection-string, you need the target database hostname (server name, or cloud service name), the port-number, the database-name, and a userid+password (or personal-certificate for Db2-for-Z/OS).  The format of the connection string is a semi-colon separated/terminated collection of X=Y pairs, like this:

`conn_string="Server=hostname_or_ip_address_of_the_Db2_server_Or_Cloud_Service;Port=50000;Database=BLUDB;UID=***;PWD=***;"`

Many other additional and optional settings can be set in that connection string to control other aspects of the connection, or to specify encryption. These are connection attributes or connection properties and are all documented in the Db2 knowledge centre.

The python code to use the connection string looks like:

`conn = ibm_db.connect( conn_string , "", "" )`

or

`conn = ibm_db.connect( conn_string, user, password)`
if you exclude the UID and PWD from the connection string and supply then as the second and third parameters to the ibm_db.connect() .

Answer (score 0):

How I managed to do in 2021. What you will need:

```
Python 3.7
PipEnv
Ibm-db
Ibm-db version is not important but this lib only works with Python 3.7 (current python version is 3.9).
```

Install Python 3.7.6 in your machine (this is the version that worked).

In your IDE create a new python file.

Let's create a Virtual Enviroment to make sure we will use Python 3.7

```
pip install pipenv
```

After installing

```
pipenv install --python 3.7
```

Activate the Virtual Environment

```
pipenv shell
```

You can use pip list to verify if you are in the new Virtual Enviroment - if list only shows 3 or 4 libs, it's because you are

Now you can download Ibm_db

```
pip install ibm-db
```

You may add this to your code to confirm what is the version you are using

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
Now accessing the DB2

import ibm_db_dbi as db

# Connect to DB2B1 (keep Protocol as TCPIP)
conn = db.connect("DATABASE=DBNAME;HOSTNAME=hostname;PORT=port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=Your User;PWD=Your Password;", "", "")
Checking all tables available

for t in conn.tables():
    print(t)
Your SQL code:

sql_for_df = """SELECT *
                FROM TABLE
                WHERE ..."""
Visualizing as DataFrame
```

First install pandas as it will not be present in your Virtual Environment

```
pip install pandas
```

After that import to your code and play around

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_sql(sql_for_df, conn) 
df.head()
```

To exit the VIrtual Enviroment just write exit in your terminal. If you want to remove the Virtual Enviroment write in the terminal pipenv --rm

That's pretty much all I could learn so far. I hope it helps you all.